# Are there any shortcuts to jump up/down directly across the manually-typed lines of a bash terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal, move

Consider that we write on terminal `cat file0.csv`, and then get 1000 lines of code. After that, we write `cat file1.csv` and then we get other 1000 lines of code. And so forth till `cat file5.csv`.

Whenever we want to go up to the last line --let's say, to check if we write `file*.csv` correctly without using `history` or reverse search, or simply to consult the first results of our commands without repeating them using `less` or `head`-- the only method we have is `SHIFT + Page Up`, but it is so tedious when there are 1000 lines of code per file. It becomes even worse when you only have `SHIFT + Page Down` and what your are looking for is not close neither to your current position nor the last line of the terminal --making `home` and `end` keys not useful for this case--.

Thus, *are there any shortcuts to jump up/down directly across the manually-typed lines of a bash terminal*?

Comment: If you use a multiplexer, like tmux, you can just do a reverse search.

Comment: try: (1) up-arrow;  (2) CTR-R pattern to reverse search; (3) PgUp

Comment: @jasonwryan Even in gnome-terminal you can search for a string that's unique in your prompt.

Comment: See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=767230 for the feature request of directly supporting it. It's unlikely to be addressed in the near future, though :(

Comment: To add to some things mentioned above you can jump to the first and last character of a prompt you are typing with the home and end keys

Comment: * For responses 1 and 2: We are interested on checking the results of the command, not the command itself.
* For @egmont 's response: Collapsible scrollback it is not exactly the feature that we were asking for, but it looks a very interesting workaround for this specific purpose. Thanks!
* For any other visitor: We are still wondering how to do this, so responses are welcome.

Comment: See [this answer to "How to quickly add some space in the terminal?"](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/210291)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>[[copy of an answer to a related question here]](/a/210291)</sup>

One approach could be to have some unique text in your prompt (I use `$` followed by a non-breaking space (`PS1=$'$\ua0'`)).

And configure your terminal emulator to scroll-back to it upon some key press.

For instance, with GNU `screen`, in `~/.screenrc`:

```
defscrollback 5000
bindkey \033` eval copy "stuff k?$\240\r"
```

Would map that to <kbd>Alt+Backtick</kbd>

I use GNU `screen` on all terminals and terminal emulators. Besides the many features brought by `screen`, that makes for a consistent experience on all of them, in particular with the scrollback handling (which is searchable, and which you can save to files or log, or copy-by-region... which most other terminal emulators are not capable to do).